D-modules on higher genus curves ($g>1$)?
After a search, I did not find much that has been said about $D$-modules on higher genus curve. I am curious if there is much known about them. Let me provide a summary of what is known first. I am focused on the algebraic setting of nonsingular projective curves over $\mathbb{C}$.

For $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$, the $D$-modules here are well understood due to the Beilinson-Bernstein Localization Theorem. In particular, $D$-modules are related to representations of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_2$.

For elliptic curves $E$, the derived category of $D$-modules can be understood via the Laumon-Rothstein Fourier transform. In this case, $D$-modules on $E$ are equivalent to coherent sheaves on $E^\natural$, the moduli space of line bundles with integrable connection.

For higher genus curves $C$, there are no references I can find. Even in the case of hyperelliptic curves $C\to \mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$, there isn't anything out there from my search.


Question: What can be said about $D$-modules on higher genus curves $g\geq 2$? In the case of hyperelliptic curves $f:C\to\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$, can anything be said about holonomic $D$-modules (recall a $D$-module $M$ on $C$ is holonomic iff $f_*M$ is holonomic and so maybe an answer can be given in this way?).
Edit (12/23/24): One thing I wanted to point out for future answers is what I'm not looking for. Recall that there is the classification of $D$-modules on a formal disk (and its punctured version) due to Levelt and Turritin. If one admits this and combines this with Beauville-Laszlo descent, then there is perhaps a way to describe $D$-modules on higher genus curves. The issue is then (a) how descent would work and (b) how $D$-modules on $C$ minus some set of points would behave. I've never seen a precise statement of how this works, but since the description is more "local" as opposed to "global" like the case of genus $0,1$, this is not a description I find as interesting.
